# Rails 1 контроллер для 2х моделей?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Жили-были 2 модели с 2мя контроллерами Category и Subcategory. Subcategory были вложены в Category.И url были у них вида categories/category-title,  categories/category-title/subcategory-title соответственно. И все было замечательно. Но пришли СЕОшники и сказали что не кошерен url более 2х уровней. И повелели сотворить url 2х уровневый вида catalog/category-title и catalog/subcategory-title.

Все бы хорошо но как быть с show в контроллере? Как определить к какому ресурсу отнести?

Насколько данный метод зело неправилен? Есть ли на свет белом более правильные методы?

Comment: Вообще в идеале надо б мигрировать `Subcategory` в `Category`. Их схемы различаются?

Comment: различаются, но не особо. тут скорее юзабилити при миграции пострадает. каталогизация и структура должна сохраниться. т.е. Category имеет несколько Subcategory, при выборе Category подгружаются соответствующие Subcategory. если все через 1 модель реализовать, то как подобное реализовать?

Comment: Ну, разница только в наличии в подкатегории `category_id`, да? Тогда ситуация понятна как минимум мне. Как успею, напишу ответ, если меня не обгонят :Р

Comment: обгонять что то нет желающих :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

URL — Uniform **Resource** Locator. Поэтому когда речь идёт об изменении урлов, речь идёт о переносе ресурсов.

В данном случае вас просят сделать урлы вида:

```
/categories/:title
```

...и вы сталкиваетесь с проблемой, что такие урлы у вас могут указывать на две разных модели.

Косяк в том, что урлы категорий и подкатегорий таким обраом на первый взгляд неразличимы. Какой это из двух ресурсов, можно понять только из текущего состояния базы, пользователь этого не поймёт по урлу. Это плохо, снижает предсказуемость. Если в базе окажется категория и подкатегория с одинаковыми названиями, одна из них будет недостижима. Упс.

Вариантов решения несколько. Перечислю пришедшие в голову в порядке "разумности".

#### Сделать урлы разными

Тут всё просто. Я приведу [три строчки для маршрутов](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources), а дальше вы догадаетесь, запустив `rake routes`:

```
resources :categories do
  resources :subcategories, shallow: true
end
```

Окей, вот примерно как оно будет выглядеть:

```
/categories/:title
/subcategories/:title
```

Два сегмента, СЕОшники довольны. Правда, на практике пользы от этого будет мало: поисковикам на это наплевать. Но я исхожу из предположения, что "вам никуда от них не деться".

#### Свести в одну модель

*Лучшее по части архтектуры, но на устранение уже нанесённого ей урона надо немного больше времени.*

По сути, чем отличаются категория от подкатегории? Категория на верхнем уровне, у неё нет "предка". Если у вас в подкатегории есть `category_id`, то... Вы смело можете в них же представить и категории, указав им предком `nil`/`NULL`. Костыль? Отнюдь, костыль **общепринятый**, реализован [библиотекой `acts_as_tree`](https://github.com/amerine/acts_as_tree), некогда бывшей частью рельс!

Порядок действий такой:

- ***Бэкап базы!***
- Добавляете колонку `parent_id` в категории.
- Копируете всё содержимое таблицы `subcategories` в `categories`, записывая значение `subcategories.category_id` в `categories.parent_id`.
- Выкидываете модель `Subcategory` и её таблицу за ненадобностью.
- Ставите `acts_as_tree` и пишете его в модель `Category`, плюс поправляете (убираете) ассоциации.
- Заменяете `Category.all` на `Category.roots` (эквив.: `Category.where(parent_id: nil)`, категории без предка).

По мере роста потребностей вы, возможно, захотите Nested Sets или Closure Tree, но это уже совсем другая история...

#### Pattern-matching в контроллере или роутах по имени категории

**Лютый хак.** Заведите в имени какой-нибудь признак, по которому можно понять, искать категорию или подкатегорию. К примеру, ведущий дефис.

Comment: спасибо за исчерпывающий ответ. надо обдумать все варианты и как они реализуются для моей задачи.