# Помогите выбрать конфигурацию моделей и баз данных для Rails приложения?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, activerecord

Здравствуйте, хочу для тренировки создать сайт на rails, что то по типу Drom но для грузовиков. Помогите как правильно организовать отношение моделей к друг другу.
Вроде все просто создаем три модели Region, User, и Tehnick,
 
у модели Region has_many Users 
у Users has_many Tehnicks
но тут поручается затык, делением техники на прицепы, тягочи, трактора. 
 
Характеристики техники разные, у трактора нет подъёмной стрелы, а у крана нет гусенец, как организовать хранение данных, и доступ к ним?
Создать кучу моделей для каждого вида техники? Или есть другие способы?
можно ли чтобы модели наследовали из класса tehnick параметры размеров и веса авто?
Зарание спасибо
[image: пример таблиц]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Доброго времени суток!

Я бы порекомендовал использовать механизм [STI](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html) вкупе с полем [jsonb](http://nandovieira.com/using-postgresql-and-jsonb-with-ruby-on-rails) для характерисик. Если кратко - то STI дает нам возможность создавать иерархию классов для "зоопарка" техники, а поле jsonb позволит записать произвольную структуру характеристик.

Comment: это как здесь описано,?https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480120/rails-1-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-2%D1%85-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B9?rq=1

Comment: Не совсем, точнее совсем не... В указанном посте речь идет конфигурации URLов.

Comment: В Вашем случае идея STI заключается в том, что  для модели Technik создается поле type, в котором будет указываться наследуемый класс, например Tractor. Вы создаете новую модель Tractor < Technik и спокойно описываете оригинальную логику и уникальные характеристики, при этом физически данные будут храниться в таблице technics. Кроме того, при запросе объекта ActiveRecord из БД рельсы будут возвращать экземпляр класса, указанного в поле type таблицы technics. Вот ссылка https://habrahabr.ru/post/79630/

Comment: понял, спасибо!